# Divs rendered side by side and stacked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I'm adapting the [hero template](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) from bootstrap.

Nested in the `hero-unit` div I would like to have two divs to be rendered in wide screens, side by side, like:

```
 |text 30% container width||picture the rest of container width|
```

and in narrow screens (smartphone) stacked:

```
|text full container width|
|picture full container width|
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots or diagrams?

Comment: You just need to float two divs and use media queries.

Comment: look at how the media queries are structured in TBS. Default size is desktop. Then there is a big desktop, phone, and tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use the built in grid system?

```
<div class="hero-unit">
  <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span3">text</div>
   <div class="span9"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to create different styles for different sized screens.

For the full size screen you could do:

```
<div id="left" class="cont">
</div>

<div id="right" class="cont">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#right{
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

The above layout will have the `left` div floating to the left, with a width of `30%` and the right div will take up the remainder of the space.

---

For the mobile screen, your CSS will vary slightly.

```
<div id="left" class="cont">

</div>

<div id="right" class="cont">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    /* Margins, padding, etc. */
}
```

Comment: This should certainly work but I'll need to learn on media queries as I have never used them. I thought there could be a simpler solution within Bootstrap framework. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @naio To use media queries you simply write `@media (page-width)` - just look at what I sent you, bootstrap already uses them if I remember correctly so you shouldn't even need to do that. All you will have to do is add the CSS that I added